# How to update two forms in a single view where one form is userChangeform(djangoform) and one is modelform (with model being userextension model)?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

[This is the user function model.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADnJS.png)

[this is the edit profile view where I need to use both forms to save in the database from html template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpL0d.png)
[These are the two forms which I need to use in one single view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGL1f.png) [This is the html template on which I need to show the contact number and be able to edit it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOyxQ.png)

I apologize if I am not able to present my question properly.
I want to be able to show and edit the contact number on the same page as other details like username, last name, and first name. I have tried different methods like using query to call from database and save both form and query on the same function but it was not updating the contact number. Can this be done or do I have to take some different approach if this can be done, please let me know? If I missed some details please let me know in case if there are question as this is my first time asking here at stack

views.py

```py
@login_required()
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            profile = user.profileModel()
            profile.contactNumber = form.cleaned_data['contactNumber']
            profile.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile'))
    else:
        form = EditProfileForm(instance = request.user)
    return render(request, 'music/edit_profile.html', {'form' : form})
```

models.py

```py
class profileModel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    contactNumber = models.IntegerField(validators=[validate_even])
    # canPOST = models.BooleanField(default =  False)
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Profile for user {}'.format(self.user.username)
```

Html file for edit profile function

```html
 <form action="{% url 'edit_profile' %}" method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleUserName1" >User Name</label>
<!--                      taking username as an input-->
                        <input type="text" name="username" value="{{ request.user.username }}" maxlength="150" required id="id_username" class="form-control" >
                        <small id="usernameHelpInline" class="text-muted">
                            Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.
                        </small>
                    </div >

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <!--                      taking first name as an input-->
                        <label for="exampleFirstName1" >First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="first_name" value="{{ request.user.first_name }}" maxlength="30" required id="id_first_name" class="form-control" >
                    </div >

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <!--                      taking last name as an input-->
                        <label for="exampleLastName1" >Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="last_name" value="{{ request.user.last_name }}" maxlength="150" required id="id_last_name" class="form-control" >
                    </div >
                        <input type="hidden" name="password" value="{{ request.user.password }}" id="id_password">
                   <!--                      submit button to edit profile -->
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Edit Profile">Edit Profile</button>
                    </form>
```

Forms.py

```py
class EditProfileForm(UserChangeForm):
    password = forms.CharField(label='', widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = {'type' : 'hidden'}))
    contactNumber = forms.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username',
                  'first_name',
                  'last_name',
                  'password',
                  ]

#User Extra Information ................
class profileInformForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = profileModel
        fields = ['contactNumber']
```

Comment: You should post the code in the question instead of redirecting to images.

Comment: Hi jabez, I have now posted the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one, you need only one form, not two. And contact number from the profile model should be CharField, not IntegerField.

```
# models.py

class ProfileModel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    contact_ number = models.IntegerField(validators=[validate_even])

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Profile for user {}'.format(self.user.username)


# forms.py
class EditProfileForm(UserChangeForm):
    password = forms.CharField(label='', widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = {'type' : 'hidden'}))
    contact_number = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username',
                  'first_name',
                  'last_name',
                  'password',
                  ]


# views.py
@login_required()
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            # profile should be one2one with profile model and then you can easily do this
            # profile = user.profile
            # with ForeignKey
            profile = user.profilemodel_set.first()  # or if has many, get the one you need to update.
            profile.contact_number = form.cleaned_data['contact_number']
            profile.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile'))
    else:
        form = EditProfileForm(instance = request.user)
    return render(request, 'music/edit_profile.html', {'form' : form})
```

Comment: I followed the same as you suggested and when I tried saving the contact number it gave me this error: " AttributeError at /edit_profile/
'User' object has no attribute 'profile' ".                                                                            
 Also, the contact number is being stored even before this during the registration of the user as this is a mandatory field so that is why I want it to be integer field only.

Comment: You are getting that error because you haven't switched from FK to O2O, i've updated my code snippet, check now. About the phone number, you can validate as int or whatever, but you should save it in db as text, unless you are not planning to do math operations with it later.

Comment: I actually did change the code to One2One from FK but still ended up getting the same error. I think since I am using the user class as an abstract. Do you think this could be the reason I am getting the AttributeError? I also tried your newly updated code still getting the same error.

Comment: Try with user.profilemodel, instead of user.profile. This is a very simple issue and easily to be fixed. Have you read the whole django docs? This part is related to the problem you have. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/

Comment: I understand what you are requiring me to do and I did the same and tried but still, the error is not going. I have updated my code snippets in the question, so let me know if I am still making mistake somewhere. I am sorry if this took some of your time and yes I did read the docs and also the one with one2one doc as well.

Comment: Great, that did the trick. Thanks a lot. So my Model name is profileModel() so how did it recognize with profilemodel? I am sorry if it is very obvious.

Comment: You welcome. It's specified in the docs, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships  - To refer to a “reverse” relationship, use the lowercase name of the model. Did you do the polls app documented in django docs?

Comment: I didn't use the reverse relationship like this which is for backward. I guess I need to go through the docs again. But thanks a lot again.